# What happened to the 'How to become the president?' question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deleted-questions

It's been over a year, but there was a simple but otherwise interesting puzzle (especially for newbies) called 'How to become the president' or something on the site.

It was basically like

```
Which of the following is correct?

a) All of the below
b) Option C
c) None of the above
d) All of the above
e) All of the above
```

I don't remember the exact options, but it was similar to what's given above. The solution was to figure out which option could be correct (and all the others incorrect) without causing a contradiction.

The question was well upvoted at the time. It was on-topic and was posted by some high rep user (maybe Gamow or rand al'thor or someone but I'm not sure) so I don't think it's likely the user got deleted. As far as I know, such a question would still be on-topic.

Here's the link I had saved on 28 March 2016

http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/26129/4269

[image: Screenshot of WhatsApp message]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It got deleted last september, I believe for plagiarism with a few others of Gamow's.

[image]

Comment: Tath sit ce pricely.

Comment: So only original puzzles are allowed? I remember there being a copy of the blue eyes puzzle also on the site. Is that also deleted?